# IAM, apply policy only to tagged instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, policies

I need create a policy IAM to stop or terminate only instances that have a specific tag (multiple instances), i have written this:

```
{
            "Action": [
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:TerminateInstances"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/Name": "tag1",
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/Name": "tag2",
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/Name": "tag3"
                }
            }
        },
```

But the form is invalid, only one string `ec2:ResourceTag/Name` can be written. How can Stop and Terminate instances with different tag `Name` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
"Condition": {
  "StringEquals": {
    "ec2:ResourceTag/Name": ["tag1","tag2","tag3"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank's i have omitted `[]`